# Variadic template overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Suppose I have a list of template parameters that can be incremented. I want to increment the head of this list. Here is the code

```
template<int N>
struct Counter {
    static constexpr Counter<N+1> increment();
};
template<int N>
constexpr Counter<N+1> Counter<N>::increment() {
    return Counter<N+1>();
}

//List (will be used as List of Counters)
template <typename... TAIL>
struct List {};

template <typename HEAD, typename... TAIL>
struct List<HEAD,TAIL...> {};



template <typename HEAD, typename... TAIL>
auto incrFront() -> decltype(List<decltype(HEAD::increment()),TAIL...>()) {
    return List<decltype(HEAD::increment()),TAIL...>();
}
```

It is indeed working :

```
auto l0 = incrFront<Counter<0>>(); // Ok, decltype(l0) == List<Counter<1>>
l0 =  List<Counter<1>>(); //Ok, right type
auto l1 = incrFront<Counter<0>,Counter<1>>();  // Ok, decltype(l1) == List<Counter<1>,Counter<1>>
l1 = List<Counter<1>,Counter<1>>();
```

Now, I would like to increment the back of the list, so

```
template <typename... HEAD, typename TAIL>
auto incrBack() -> decltype(List<decltype(HEAD...,TAIL::increment())>()) {
    return List<decltype(HEAD...,TAIL::increment()>();
}
```

But got error 'incrBack' was not declared in this scope

I tried to add another method before this one:

```
template <typename... HEAD>
auto incrBack() -> decltype(List<HEAD...>()) {
    std::cout << "Should not be here\n";
    return List<HEAD...>();
}
```

Hoping that this method would never get called when resolving overloading, but this method is indeed called.

Any clue ? I just want this example to be working :

```
auto l2 = incrBack<Counter<1>,Counter<1>>();  // I want decltype(l2) == List<Counter<1>,Counter<2>>
l2 = incrFront<Counter<0>,Counter<2>>();  //should be possible
```

Comment: A variadic pack swallows *any and all arguments*, `TAIL` will never have a type and `incrBack` is removed from overload resolution.

Comment: You'd need recursion to eat up all the arguments until you arrive to the last and increment it.

Comment: Is that really how you want `incrFront` to work? Because there's no deduction and the list isn't encapsulated by anything, you have to call it with an explicit parameter pack every time. Sort of defeats the purpose, no?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use [`boost::mpl`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html)?

Comment: Ah, damn, this question requires a bit of a different mechanic than I thought at first - it's not only access to the end, but also preserving the whole list before that.

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin Only one reason: lack of knowledge :) Seriously, I'll take a look. Boost is really powerful, but quite large...

Comment: @Potatoswatter Well the code is simplified for better understanding but I don't know if what I'm doing is the best way. List objects (well,types) are generated by other methods. But are you thinking of sth in particular ? Any reference is welcomed !

Comment: @BérengerBerthoul Don't oversimplify. Does `incrFront` operate on a `List` or does it only operate on a pack and return a `List`?

Comment: @Potatoswatter It operates on a pack an returns a list (because I can't return a pack). Now, incr() is in fact algo(int), a quite tricky algorithm (IMHO). And there is sort of a reverse algo that operates on a list and which returns an int, lets call it revAlgo(List), such that we can have algo(revAlgo(int) = int. The reverse algo operates on the head of the list (and works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, write your code to operate on `List<>` instead of naked variardic type lists, it will be easier.

Second, instead of working with template functions, work with template classes.

```
template<typename T>
struct inc {
  typedef decltype(T::increment()) type;
};
template<typename T>
using Inc = typename inc<T>::type;
```

now we can talk about `Inc<HEAD>` instead of `decltype( HEAD::increment() )`, which should make your code far more readable.

Write the following `template` classes:

```
template<typename List, typename T>
struct append;
template<typename List, typename T>
using Append = typename append<List,T>::type;
template<template<typename...>class TypeList, typename... Ts, typename T>
struct append<TypeList<Ts...>, T> {
  typedef TypeList<Ts..., T> type;
};
template<typename List>
struct reverse;
template<typename List>
using Reverse = typename reverse<List>::type;
template<template<typename...>class TypeList>
struct reverse<TypeList<>> {
  typedef TypeList<> type;
};
template<template<typename...>class TypeList, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct reverse<TypeList<T0, Ts...>> {
  typedef Append< Reverse<TypeList<Ts...>>, T0 > type;
};
```

and similar ones.  Note that I operate on types, and I specialize on types produced from some generic variardic pack of types passed to a `template` -- this means I'm not tied to working with one way to pack variardic args into a single type.

I also write `template` aliases to reduce the `typename` spam.

Next, apply functor:

```
template<template<typename>class Func, typename List>
struct apply_to_first;
template<template<typename>class Func, typename List>
using ApplyToFirst = typename apply_to_first<Func, List>::type;
template<template<typename>class Func, template<typename...>class TypeList, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct apply_to_first<Func, TypeList<T0, Ts...>> {
  typedef TypeList< typename Func<T0>::type, Ts... > type;
};
```

and then `IncFirst`:

```
template<typename List>
using IncFirst = ApplyToFirst< inc, List >;
```

which is now pretty short.

As for `IncLast`, it is marginally harder:

```
template<typename List>
using IncLast = Reverse< IncFirst < Reverse<List> > >;
```

but still fits on one line.  Still, I'd prefer this more verbose version:

```
template<template<typename>class Func, typename List>
using ApplyToLast = Reverse< ApplyToFirst< Func, Reverse<List> > >;

template<typename List>
using IncLast = ApplyToLast< inc, List >;
```

Now, I did not directly answer your question, in that I never wrote `incrFront` (nor did I compile the above, so it could be full of syntax errors).

So here is `incrFirst` and `incrLast` after you have moved the heavy lifting to the above mini metaprogramming library:

```
template<typename... Ts>
IncFirst<List<Ts...>> incrFirst() {
  return IncFirst<List<Ts...>>();
}
template<typename... Ts>
IncLast<List<Ts...>> incrLast() {
  return IncLast<List<Ts...>>();
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks very much. It is quite difficult for me to understand cause I am new to this kind of things. But I see that the key point here is "Reverse". I also thought of sth like that but was unable to implement it. Do you have any reference or net tutorial on this kind of TMP with C++11 ("Modern C++ Design" seems good but is not up-to-date...)

Comment: @BérengerBerthoul not that I know of.  Much of these techniques are relatively new, in that they didn't exist prior to C++11.  Learning a language like LISP or Haskell can be of great help, because C++11 TMP is a functional programming language, and techniques used in mature functional programming languages can inform relatively young languages like C++11 TMP.  :)